# How to handle exceptions in Socket programming VB.net

Tags: vb.net, sockets, exception, client

I'm writing an client/server application using VB.net.
I used the code from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx) to connect to a server :

```
' ManualResetEvent instances signal completion.
Private Shared connectDone As New ManualResetEvent(False)
Private Shared sendDone As New ManualResetEvent(False)
Private Shared receiveDone As New ManualResetEvent(False)

' The response from the remote device.
Private Shared response As String = String.Empty


Public Shared Sub Main()
    ' Establish the remote endpoint for the socket.
    ' For this example use local machine.
    Dim ipHostInfo As IPHostEntry = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName())
    Dim ipAddress As IPAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList(0)
    Dim remoteEP As New IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port)

    ' Create a TCP/IP socket.
    Dim client As New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)

    ' Connect to the remote endpoint.
    client.BeginConnect(remoteEP, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ConnectCallback), client)

    ' Wait for connect.
    connectDone.WaitOne()

    ' Send test data to the remote device.
    Send(client, "This is a test<EOF>")
    sendDone.WaitOne()

    ' Receive the response from the remote device.
    Receive(client)
    receiveDone.WaitOne()

    ' Write the response to the console.
    Console.WriteLine("Response received : {0}", response)

    ' Release the socket.
    client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both)
    client.Close()
End Sub 'Main
```

The code works perfectly but it doesn't handle exceptions mainly timeout exception.
I changed it as follows:

```
Private ConnectionDone As New ManualResetEvent(False)    

Public Function SendNetworkRequest(ByVal IPAddress As IPAddress, ByVal Port As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim RemoteEndPoint As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress, Port)

    'TCP/IP Socket
    Dim Client As New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)        

    'Start connection
    Try
        Client.BeginConnect(RemoteEndPoint, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ConnectCallBack), Client)
        ConnectionDone.WaitOne()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    Return True
End Function

Private Sub ConnectCallBack(ByVal Ar As IAsyncResult)
    Dim Socket As Socket = CType(Ar.AsyncState, Socket)
    Socket.EndConnect(Ar)
    MsgBox("connected to " & Socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString())
    ConnectionDone.Set()
End Sub
```

But when executed with a wrong IP address and port to raise the exception, the application just stops without doing anything. Knowing that this function is called from a Form_Load event, even the following MsgBox("loaded") is not executed.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    SendNetworkRequest(GV_ServerAddress, GV_ServerPort)
    MsgBox("Loaded")
End Sub
```

does any on know the reason of this sudden exit ?
thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is `ConnectCallBack`?  I don't see it in your posted code.

Comment: I added the ConnectCallBack method.